# Jquery jquery.sumoselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sumoselect.js

Im trying to use a plugin called jquery.sumoselect from https://github.com/HemantNegi/jquery.sumoselect the thing is everything is well documented but the thing i realy want to know is how do i get the selected values of it missing in documentation or i keep reading over and over it ?
does someone knows where or how to do it ?
I needed it for a asp.net usercontrol im making of it so.
very handy to know how i get the selected values.

Comment: This is a valid question!! I don't know why **downvotes** for this!! But an issue has been already reported in _Git_ by some user to include it as feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply read the values from the input that SumoSelect is operating on. So if you apply it like this `$('.testselect1').SumoSelect();` then simply run `$('.testselect1').val();` to get the selected value. You can access the [SumoSelect demo page](http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/sumoselect_demo.html) and open the browser console and run `$('.testselect1').val();` to see.

This is somewhat expected for a jQuery plugin -- see jQuery [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Very Ty mr Cymen thats what i was looking for :)